# Trying to create a PBI report column that counts the items from a list

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a data model with 3 tables :

[image]

I have a report that shows how many items were sold in a given transaction. I would like to add a column to the report that shows of the items sold, how many were in a particular item list :

[image]

Ive tried creating a new measure using FILTER and COLUMNCOUNT, but it doesnt seem to like having 3 tables as part of it.

Comment: You probably need something like COUNTROWS(
INTERSECT( VALUES( ItemList[ItemID]), Purchases[ItemID] ) )

Comment: @Brett Fry for the second row it should be 0 for items bought from list no ?